# Same source code compiling in various languages

Tags: terminology, language-agnostic

What do you call source code valid in several languages? There was a specific word for it and really crazy examples.

Comment: Going in the opposite direction, here is a pretty amazing list of [languages that compile to JavaScript](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The word you are looking for [Polyglot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_%28computing%29)

> a computer program or script written in a valid form of multiple programming languages, which performs the same operations or output independent of the programming language used to compile or interpret it.
>
> Generally polyglots are written in a combination of C (which allows redefinition of tokens with a preprocessor) and a scripting language such as Lisp, Perl or sh...